# Как настроить nginx?

Tags: apache, nginx, веб-сервер, debian, linux

log nginx

> 2012/11/28 17:55:30 [error] 3090#0: *5 directory index of "/var/www/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "a.localhost1"

вывод

> 403 forbidden

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

> NameVirtualHost *:8080Listen* :8080

/etc/apache2/sites-available/a

> VirtualHost *:8080>

В чём ошибка и как исправить?без nginx все работает.

Comment: Дык, а nginx че делает то? Проксирует или то же что и апач, файлик читает,отдает?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*5 directory index of "/var/www/" is forbidden,
```

Ну значит права на папку стоят только для апача, если он тоже стоит, если не стоит, то поставить на папку www права пользователя от которого запущен nginx